# Same local database from different assemblies not working

Tags: c#, database, configuration, localdb

I'm trying to have one local database when using EF and code first. I have three projects - DataLayer, Web and Console App.

In Web.config in the Web project, I have following connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In the App.config in the Console App I have exactly the same connection string, but when I try to read data in the console app from the database, it doesn't find the data I've created from the web project. Why is this?

When I add the connection (Host: (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB, Db: MyDb) in Server Explorer Data Connections I can see the tables with the data from the web project, but not from the console app. Both apps are using DataContext and Models from the DataLayer project.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Since I was running the Console App as a service logged on as system, the databases where separate. I changed the service to run as my windows account and it worked.